# Where does the config line go for a sub-project in an sbt multi-build?

Tags: scala, sbt

When creating a sub project in an sbt multi-build, I'm following the instructions in [the official docs found here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html).

I'm placing the following line into my `build.sbt` file.

```
lazy val MySubProject = project
```

And then when I run sbt I'm getting the following error.

```
$ sbt
/home/d/projects/test/build.sbt:7: error: illegal start of simple expression
lazy val MySubProject = project
^
```

What noobie mistake am I making? Where does the line go?

Comment: Can you provide the content of all the .sbt files in the project ? The lazy val is valid in a .sbt file so I assume there is another problem. check the build of https://github.com/jeantil/playLastik/ for a simple 2 modules build

Comment: I found the problem. I thought I was using sbt 0.13, but it was actually sbt 0.12. I upgraded to version 0.13 and now everything works. Thanks for the help @Jean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was because I used an older version of sbt.

The line `lazy val MySubProject = project` does belong in `build.sbt` (though it could otherwise be put in `project/build.scala`).

I thought I was running sbt 0.13, but I was actually running sbt 0.12.

After upgrading sbt to version 0.13, everything works correctly.